# How can I override the current EditText input as soon as the user clicks a button?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

In my app I have an EditText where the users types in his answer to a question and then hits the ok button. When his answer is right there will be an image showing that he has answered right. If his answer is wrong there is an image that his answer is wrong. What I now want is when the users answer is wrong he can type in another answer, so I need a function that when the user clicks any button of the keyboard, the old edit text input will be overridden by the new input. I just managed that when the user clicks any button of the keyboard that the EditText will be cleared, but it will not be overwritten by the new input.

Does anyone has any suggestions? I did not find any answers here.

```
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        if (!answered.equals("true")) {
            // Add Text Watcher on name input text
            editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                    wrongAnswer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    if (clearText) {
                        editText.getText().clear();
                        clearText = false;
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                    //This method prevents that the player types in a zero as first number
                    if (s.toString().length() == 1 && s.toString().startsWith("0")) {
                        s.clear();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: What new input is there if only a button is clicked?

Comment: I have a custom keyboard with only numbers and a ok button. After hitting the ok button the user sees if his answer is right or wrong. If it is wrong he can again type any number, so the edit text still holds e.g. 1985 as previous input and then the user hits the number one and then I want that the edit text is cleared and the number one is the new input

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what u need:

```
Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener { //set onclicklistener for button
    @override
    onClick() {
       if (!answered.equals("true")) { //check if answer is wrong
           editText.setText(""); //set text to empty
           answerImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.wrong); //set image to wrong
       }
}
```

Hope this helps you! Happy coding:)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this does not help me. The EditText should be cleared after the user hits a new number of the keyboard and overwrite the old input with whatever the user clicked

Comment: ok, then you have to use the if condition within afterTextChanged function and not outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `editText.setText("your new text")`method when you click the button to change the text of your editText